# Pandas closing django-like file, gives ValueError: I/O operation on closed file when uploading

Tags: django, pandas

In my process i need to upload a file to django as:

```
newFile = request.FILES['file']
```

then in another big function i open it with pandas:

```
data = pandas.read_csv(data_file, engine = 'python', header=headers_row, encoding = 'utf-8-sig')
```

and then i need to upload it

```
uploaded_file = Uploaded_file(file = newFile, retailer = ret, date = date)
```

but randomly (like 50/50) i get a ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Any solution to this? is it possible to open the file again or maybe make a copy of it and use pandas in one and upload the other?

I tried the later but i'm not sure of the implications of going this route:

```
from io import BytesIO
output = BytesIO(newFile.file.read())
```

for now it works but i'd appreciate any input on this